# how to change the texture of the material from polished to natural chipped

Tags: materials

I have a picture of polished granite. I want to transform that material so that it looks like natural chipped as attached below. first of all is it possible if so how?
1) I tried creating a normal map of natural chipped but my reference image is very small so I cant use it on the larger surface without tiling 
2) how do I transform the polished granite to look like a rough granite, I have no idea on how to approach this

[image: polished and natural chipped][image: polished refernce]

Answer (score 1):

You could do it **procedurally**:

Use 2 *Noise* nodes that you mix into a *MixRGB* (*Overlay* mode) node. Then you can add some glossiness or bumpiness, it all depends on the realism you want to give to your material...

[image]